# Trying to pass a click handler to an Apollo Query through props

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I am trying to pass a click handler through props from this class

```
class App extends Component {
 handleToggle = (todo:any) => () => {
  // update todo 
  console.log("I WORK!");
};

 render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todos onTodoClick={this.handleToggle}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

to this function that contains a `Query` :

```
  function Todos(props: any) {
    return (
      <Query query={GET_TODOS}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return "Loading...";
          if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
          return (
            <div>
              <List>
                {data.todos.map((todo: any) => (
                  <ListItem
                    key={todo.id}
                    onClick={() => props.onTodoClick(todo)} // HERE
                  >
                     <ListItemText primary={todo.text} />
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
```

But, no matter whether I make `Todo` a function or just a const, that props click handler never gets called. I am hoping to see "I WORK!" in the console, but it's not happening. Any ideas how to pass the click handler through the props when the receiving function contains an Apollo Query?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I'm silly. I wrote the `handleToggle` badly. It should've been:

```
handleToggle = (todo:any) => {
  // update todo 
  console.log("I WORK!");
};
```

And inside `App`, call `Todos` with

```
<Todos onTodoClick={()=>this.handleToggle}/>
```